# Apache Rules for JS/CSS versioning using mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've been trying this for the last 2h.

how can I use mod rewrite to do this:

/assets/app.min.4364736473.js -> /assets/app.min.js
/assets/app.min.4364736473.css -> /assets/app.min.css

Comment: Perhaps you could choose an answer to accept? It would be good to mark the question completed. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not that there's anything wrong with nikoshr's answer, but perhaps this is more versatile, working anywhere in the site that the format is used, since it's not likely to be used for any usual extension. In case it is, it checks that the file with the number doesn't exist before executing. The `.min` is optional, it works with or without it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.\d+(\.(?:js|css))$ $1$2
```

Finally, not using the `[L]` flag since other rules might need to be applied on the rewritten URL and no need to stop that happening.

It will only work properly in a `.htaccess` or `<Directory>` context. Otherwise (in a root config or `<VirtualHost>` context) it will need modifying for the file test to work or existing files won't be noticed and it will execute anyway.

Comment: I try to stick to the simplest rules that can do the job but yours can be useful

Comment: Awesome ! Works perfect.

Answer (score 2):

It could be

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /assets/app\.min\.\d+\.js$ /assets/app.min.js [L]
RewriteRule /assets/app\.min\.\d+\.css$ /assets/app.min.css [L]
```

Comment: ty..nope can't get it to work. I had something similar to begin with

RewriteRule /assets/app\.min\.\d+\.(js|css)$ $1.$3 [L]

Comment: got it :) there was uppercase letter i in the name so \d+ wasn't working...